# Formatting hdd to ext3 fails?

Tags: linux, partition, usb, ext3

What's the command to format my external 2.5 Tb USB hdd to ext3? Using `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdc1` works, but only gives me 300 Gb of space allocated -- where am I failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `parted`:

```
parted /dev/sdc
```

and do the following in it:

```
mklabel gpt
mkpart primary ext3 4MiB -1MiB
quit
```

Only then try to format it:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdc1
```

As a side note: fsck on a 2.5TB partition will take a *long long* time, use ext4 if you can, jfs or xfs otherwise.

Comment: +1 for using ext4.  mkfs also takes forever on a disk that big with ext3.  With ext4 it should only take a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a master boot record partition table? If so, that could be the problem. MBR partition tables are only good up to 2 TB. Use GPT instead (GUID Partition Table, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).

Comment: when using GPT i can't mount it, really don't know why... i try to reformat! thanks

Comment: @Tronic: can you give last few lines of output from `dmesg` when you try to mount the partition on GPT partitioned drive?